# Saving User Edited Tabulator Table from Panel library in Python

Tags: python, panel, holoviews, tabulator-py

I am building a panel dashboard and would like to dynamically save a tabulator widget table that has been edited by a user into a DataFrame.

This is what I have tried, but it errors out on me

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import panel as pn
import holoviews as hv

table=pn.widgets.Tabulator(df)
template=pn.template.MaterialTemplate(title=“Title”)
template.main.append(pn.row(table)
template.servable()
print(table.value)
```

Comment: Whats the exact error message you received ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.